# Ignore few Documents with conditions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

after some aggregations I came up with following root level documents.

```
{ _id:"id_1", isPublished:true, lookingFor:"Banner", name:"Math"},
{ _id:"id_2", isPublished:true, lookingFor:"Banner", name:"English"},
{ _id:"id_3", isPublished:true, lookingFor:"Banner", name:"Science"},
{ _id:"id_4", isPublished:false, lookingFor:"Banner",name:"Health"},
{ _id:"id_5", isPublished:false, lookingFor:"Banner",name:"Religion"}
{ _id:"id_6", isPublished:false, lookingFor:"Featured",name:"Sports"}
```

The above documents are sorted based on `{ $sort: { "_id": 1, "isPublished": -1 }}`.
I have to get only **first document** of Banner if `isPublished:true` **AND** `lookingFor:"Banner"`. Otherwise get all in same order.

Expected Result is

```
{ _id:"id_1", isPublished:true, lookingFor:"Banner", name:"Math"},
{ _id:"id_4", isPublished:false, lookingFor:"Banner",name:"Health"},
{ _id:"id_5", isPublished:false, lookingFor:"Banner",name:"Religion"}
{ _id:"id_6", isPublished:false, lookingFor:"Featured",name:"Sports"}
```

I don't understand how to do this in ROOT level. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can group and push the documents into an array, say `docs`. Next, in a `$addFields` stage iterate over the array with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) array operator and accumulate your results based upon the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of approaches to this issue:

1. Depending on scale this might not be well suited, however it will be the easiest to implement into your pipeline as it could be added seamlessly.

Add either this:

```
[
    {
        $facet: {
            one: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        isPublished: true,
                        lookingFor: "Banner"
                    }
                },
                {
                    $limit: 1
                }
            ],
            rest: {
                $match: {
                    $or: [
                        {
                            isPublished: {$ne: true},
                        },
                        {
                            lookingFor: {$ne: "Banner"}
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        project: {
            merged: {
                $concatArrays: ["$one", "$rest"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$merged"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$merged"
        }
    }
]
```

Or this:

```
[
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {pub: "$isPublished", banner: "$lookingFor"},
            roots: {$push: "$$ROOT"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            roots: {
                $cond: [
                    {
                        $and: [
                            {$eq: ["$_id.pub", true]},
                            {$eq: ["$_id.banner", "Banner"]},
                        ]
                    },
                    {$slice: ["$roots", 1]},
                    "$roots"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$roots"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$roots"
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see both of these require data restructuring on the entire result set making this approach not scaleable.

2. Depending on your previous aggregation which you have not published it might be better to just split this logic into 2 different calls:

```
db.collection.findOne({isPublished: true, lookingFor: "Banner"})
```

+

```
db.collection.find({$or: [{isPublished: {$ne: true}}, {lookingFor: {$ne: "Banner"}})
```

Again depending on previous logic this might actually be more efficient. I also recommend you make sure you have the appropriate index to support this query.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the try, But as I already mentioned, These are the top level documents (IN ROOT). So I feel `$facet` cannot be used. I created  a mongoplaground https://mongoplayground.net/p/5kCRJQXQoF_ . Please check this

Comment: `$facet` is an aggregation operator and not a query one.